# Use list in Grafana Variables

Tags: visualization, grafana, dashboard, metrics, grafana-variable

I have different Grafana dashboards build on Graphite datasources.
And add variable with such values:

```
grp1,grp2,grp3,grp4
```

Now I can choose any group in dropdown menu and it works perfectly
[image]

Also I can write in the query body something like:
`{grp2,grp4}` to get sum of this two groups.

My question - how to make variable value that combine several possible values?
I mean I want to add to dropdown menu more options like some combinations
I tried the same way in Variables menu:

```
grp1,grp2,grp3,grp4,{grp2,grp4}
```

but this doesnt works - it create values like `{grp2` and `grp4}`
[image: grafana]
Also I tried to use `All`option here in the menu, but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape comma with `\`, e.g.:

```
grp1,grp2,grp3,grp4,{grp2\,grp4}
```

so `{grp2,grp4}` will be one item in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your solution is just a half way, but now I got the right way :)
your approach correctly displays in dropdown menu but show no data. You need to upgrade it this way for correct work: `{grp2\,grp4}`. Edit please and I will accept your answer!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam done, but please edit your question with query and used datasource type. Curly bracket syntax is datasource specific, it isn't generic syntax for all datasource types.

Comment: Done! ;) Thank you